# Incompréhensible crash

Tags: android

I'm creating an application which translate user's texts.

First, my code was :

```
textToReadEdittext.setText(TranslateManager.translate(text, from, to));
```

Now I need to use the translated text for an other thing. So I use a String variable :

```
String translatedText = TranslateManager.translate(text, from, to);
textToReadEdittext.setText(translatedText);
```

But now my application crashes! There is the logs from Eclipse :

```
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not   execute method of the activity
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    at fr.robinkaminski.devAndroid.projetthalie.activities.KeyboardActivity.keyboardTranslateListener(KeyboardActivity.java:44)
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    ... 11 more
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    at fr.robinkaminski.devAndroid.projetthalie.translate.TranslateManager.translate(TranslateMana ger.java:74)
03-21 20:24:58.437: E/AndroidRuntime(14867):    ... 15 more
```

I don't understand why my activity crashes. Can you help me?

Thx, korax.

Comment: You get a NullPointer from your Translatemanager.translate(...) method. So maybe a parameter (text, from, to) is null and this causes the NullPointer or there is something wrong in your method

Answer (score 0):

Either your text or from or to is null. Check them before passing to TranslateManager and print it out if any of them are null.

Comment: I'm gonna try your ideas. But I don't understand, the 2 codes are the same?

Comment: The problem come from the Bing API. Even through my web browser it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you print out the params before calling the method?